# Short way to filter entries where at least one column contains given value

Tags: sql, oracle

I have a table where among others there are several columns with numeric data. Say,

```
+-------+----+----+----+
| COL_A | T1 | .. | TN |
+-------+----+----+----+
| SMTH1 | 10 | .. | 55 |
+-------+----+----+----+
| SMTH2 | 77 | .. | 12 |
+-------+----+----+----+
```

I need to query only the rows where any of `T` columns contains the value `12`. The long way to go is to use `where` clause like

```sql
WHERE T1 = 12 OR T2 = 12 OR ... OR TN = 12;
```

**Is there a shorter way?** The only approach that is coming to my mind is to concatenate values and then check if it matches a regular expression.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `IN`;

```
where 12 in (t1, t2, . . . )
```